# 80s/90s book about kids travelling to alternate dimension/time traveling

Tags: story-identification, novel

Wondering if someone can help me – although I think this is a very long shot as my memory is vague:

I used to read this book/series in the 90s. The story involved a gang of kids/teens battling with ”Ooze” or ”slime” of some kind. Also there was an alternative dimension which the children traveled to occasionally, like a mirror version of the town they lived in. It's also possible that they were traveling to the future ? I remember the town was desolate and abandoned in this alternate timeline/dimension.

The only other detail I remember is that the kids traveled to this mirror-town and found a gravestone with another child’s name scratched into it. The name was something ”Poole”. Shane Poole?

that’s literally all I remember haha. If anyone knows what I’m talking about please let me know!

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.